# Call a stored procedure from another stored procedure using the returned value from a SELECT statement as an argument for said stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am using the 'Procedures' GUI in phpMyAdmin and I have a SP that has one IN param which it uses to return some info, part of which is used to call a second SP. I currently have it set up so that when the first SP has returned I use the ID to call a second SP. So I end up with multiple DB calls when I only want one and for the DB to do the heavy lifting.

The second SP is on another DB as well, both DB's are on the same server.

I want to return the results from both the SP and the initial SELECT statement.

I thought that this would work:

```
SELECT result1, @id = result2, result3, result4 FROM somewhere WHERE this = that
CALL DB2.second_sp(@id)
```

Comment: Should work with `@id := result2`. `:=` is the assignment operator, `=` is a simple comparison.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is giving me an error saying that there is an error in the syntax near 'CALL DB2.second_sp(@id)'

Comment: Add a `;` after your first statement.

Comment: Nope; I tried to save the SP with just defining the CALL by itself and it saved fine; I then tried with just the first SELECT and it saved fine. putting them together is causing the syntax error. I also added the ';' to the end of the SELECT statement.

Comment: Then change the delimiter and put the statements in a `BEGIN...END` block, if that is all in another procedure.

Comment: Tried `BEGIN SELECT result1, @id = result2, result3, result4 FROM somewhere WHERE this = that;
CALL DB2.second_sp(@id); END` but this just ran the select statement and got nothing back from the SP. I'll double check

Comment: That is the whole damn code just with renamed params. As far as errors go; I'm not getting any; as I said it's running but not returning anything for the SP. Thanks for your help so far on this I'll just guess by myself from now.

Comment: That's probably because you're still using the comparison operator, not the assignment operator, like I told you in the very first comment. Your variable is probably still `NULL`, when you haven't initialized it with some value.

Comment: Sorry that comment that shows the code is wrong I forgot to type the ':' before the comparison operator. So the code is what you kindly suggested, just silently failing on me.

Comment: And what I meant with the whole code, is, that you're talking about a stored procedure calling another procedure. I don't see any procedure declaration. This is probably a very simple matter, once you post the whole code. And with your problem that you get nothing back from the procedure, we can't help either in any way, when we have no idea, what the procedure is doing at all. Think about it.

Comment: And edit code in your question, don't post it in the comments.

Comment: As I said that is the whole code, I have a stored procedure that runs the SELECT statement, I added the CALL to the second SP after the SELECT in the hopes of getting back both returned data rows instead of doing it via PHP; i.e call SP1, get response, call SP2, etc. There is no declaration as I have created them via the phpMyAdmin GUI as per my question. Unless you still need to declare them, I'm unsure as I am new to SQL/MySQL